# Dynamic time in Excel spreadsheet column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I am trying to automate time in Excel. I have two columns that show time advancing in minutes and seconds. I want to be able to automate so that if the time changes in one row, it will automatically correct in the times that follow that row. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use relative references. Would you make your question a little bit more clear? You say you have columns but you want the rows to change. How does it look?

Comment: 7:57 AM 8:01 AM
8:01 AM 8:05 AM
8:03 AM 8:07 AM
8:05 AM 8:09 AM
8:09 AM 8:13 AM

Comment: Sorry, the times are in two columns, I want them to automatically change if one time changes, for example, if the time 7:57 changes to 8:03, I want the next row below to reflect the change and become 8:06 from 8:01 automatically without me having to manually change all of the times that follow.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this: in the first cell put your first time. In your example it is `7:57` in `A1`

In `A2` put `=A1+time(0,4,0)` and drag that down column A. This will make every time at 4 minute intervals be dependent on `A1`. If you change `A1` to `8:01`, everything else changes. The formula is `=time(hours,minutes,seconds)` adjust accordingly